# contents_for not displaying when set in layout to be retrieved in action view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

First of all, I'm using Rails `3.1.1` and Ruby `1.9.3-p0`. After experimenting for a few hours on my existing project and a new "sanity check" project, I can confirm that this doesn't seem to work. I've tried in both HAML and ERB but here is the HAML version. First the layout file:

```
/ application.html.haml
- content_for :stuff, "some content"
#content
  = yield  # lets say we are in the show action
```

Followed by the action view:

```
/ show.html.haml
= content_for :stuff
```

The result is that **nothing** gets displayed. I hope I am extremely wrong of course because I really need to be able to do this and it seems like this is one of those common scenarios. Shouldn't this work or no? If not, could I get a suggestion on a good alternative? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if your problem has to do with ruby version, but 1.9.3 is not a supported version and you should avoid it.

Comment: @PauloAbreu i think people are being actively encouraged to run stuff on 1.9.3. I am sure Rails is being totally supported on 1.9.x. Perhaps support for 1.9.1 might be dropped in the near future. Regardless, the problem in this particular case is not related to ruby version.

Comment: @AdityaSanghi Ruby on Rails website is very clear about 1.9.1: is not supported (http://rubyonrails.org/download). But due to the nature of Rails, is possible that this information is outdated.

Comment: Action's view gets rendered before the layout. Can u explain your requirement please? Im sure there is an easy answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went through the source code and I discovered that this is actually not possible because templates are rendered before the layout file. I have yet to come up with an alternative solution.

Comment: I really don't understand your requirement. Why do you need to define content for a view in its layout?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know HALM but it seems you are inverting the right order.

You define the content_for in your layout (application.html.erb)

```
<%= content_for :something if a_test %>
```

And what should replaced with in your view

```
<% content_for :something do %>
  Hello World
<% end %>
```

Comment: It's not inverted because I want to display my `content_for` in the action view, not in the layout. Rather, I want to set my `content_for` in the layout, and display it in the action view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just got it wrong. Here is the corrected code with some explanation:

```
/ application.html.haml
#content
  = yield(:stuff)  # lets say we are in the show action

/ show.html.haml
- content_for :stuff do
  = "Some content with #{some.computation}"
```

What I have changed:

- In your `application.html.haml`, you have to specify the structure, and then denote the content. This is done by `yield(:stuff)`.
- In your file `show.html.haml`, you define what the content of `stuff` is. This is normally done with a block, but could be done like: `- content_for :stuff, "My content"`.

After your comment, I have understood what you really wanted to reach. Just to be sure, I think you want the following:

- Define the content of something in the `application.html.haml` file.
- Use that content in only some of the view files (in the example `show.html.haml` for one controller).

First, I don't understand why you would do something like that. And second, yes, views get rendered first. The only option you have is to include definition and usage in your `application.html.haml` file like that:

```
/ application.html.haml
- content_for :stuff, "some content"
#content
  = yield(:stuff) if controller.action_name == 'show'
```

Comment: this is the correct answer. Use yield(:stuff) to output stuff and content_for :stuff { } to send stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however this is not the functionality that I want. I want to be able to set the `content_for` in the application layout file, not within the action view. Is there no way I can do that?